# How do I cancel Pending Intents in a Android Widget?

Tags: android, android-intent, widget, android-pendingintent

I've got some weird behavior and I can only assume is because of the Pending intents I am using.

**Scenario**

I have a widget (4x1) which has 4 buttons. Within onUpdate of the widget, I add an pending intent for each button. My intents fires a Service with a bundeled parameter and depending on this parameter starts something. I attach intents as this:

```
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);

Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("myVariable", someVariable);

Intent intent = new Intent(context, AppStarterService.class);
intent.putExtras(b);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, buttopnPosition, intent, 0);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnOne, pendingIntent);
```

**The problem**

The code works just fine, until the user decides to update the content of the button. Then, a new Pending Intent is done. So, when I press again the button, sometimes it still executes the old intent and not the new one. I don't know how to explain this better. Let's say for my first intent the parameter is "TestOne", after my update, the new intent has parameter "TestX". When the user clicks on the button, on my service I get in intent extras still "TestOne" instead "TestX". So, my guess is that somehow, I need to cancel the previous intent, when the widget button content changes. 
Is this the issue ? Am I doing something wrong ? How do I cancel the old intent, I need to recreate it and then cancel it ?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have you tried *pendingIntent.cancel();* before *views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnOne, pendingIntent);* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I you keep having this problem even with FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT, try defining a different *requestCode* each time, with something like this:

```
private static int request = 0;
...
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, request++, intent, 0);
```

So each time a new PendingIntent is created, a new requestCode is used, at least during class life.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to set the flag http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT as the last parameter to PendingIntent.getService